# Vuejs method ajax call other method on component

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, components

how to call another method inside jquery ajax?

```
methods : {
    calert(type,msg="",error=""){
        console.log("call me");
    },
    getData(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data){
                // error calert not found
                calert(true,"","asd");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                // also error calert not found
                this.calert(false,"",error);
            },
            complete: function(){
            },
            url: "/test",
        });
    },
}
```

i have try to using `this.calert` but it doesn't work, still error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to update your code to use arrow functions, as follows:

```
methods : {
    calert(type,msg="",error=""){
        console.log("call me");
    },
    getData(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            success: (data) => {
                this.calert(true,"","asd");
            },
            error: (error) => {
                this.calert(false,"",error);
            },
            complete: (){
            },
            url: "/test",
        });
    },
}
```

Or alternatively, store a local reference to the method, like:

```
methods : {
    calert(type,msg="",error=""){
        console.log("call me");
    },
    getData(){
        const { calert } = this;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data){
                // error calert not found
                calert(true,"","asd");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                // also error calert not found
                calert(false,"",error);
            },
            complete: function(){
            },
            url: "/test",
        });
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

btw i found the solution, looks like little bit tricky using this

```
methods : {
    calert(type,msg="",error=""){
        console.log("call me");
    },
    getData(){
        let vm = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data){
                // error calert not found
                vm.calert(true,"","asd");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                // also error calert not found
                vm.calert(false,"",error);
            },
            complete: function(){
            },
            url: "/test",
        });
    },
}
```

i store the `this` to variable and then i use the variable to call another methods.

Anyone have any solutions better than this?

Thanks

Comment: assigning `this` to variable has been made obsolete with the introduction of arrow functions, which have access to global context. just use them in ajax callbacks. for ex: `success: (data) => this.calert(true, "", "asd")`